# Jenkins Trigger X minutes after last build

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

We have recently switched from CruiseControl.Net to Jenkins for managing our builds.  With CCNET it would trigger a new build X minutes after the last one completed, but with Jenkins it is constantly dropping builds in the queue, not allowing any time in between the two.   We'd prefer the CCNET method.

- I don't see how this can be done with the Scheduler Trigger, it seems to be all date time based.
- I don't see any setting to prevent Queueing another build where the build is currently running.
- I don't see a trigger that would allow for timing based off last run.

How could I manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins lets you set a quiet period between builds, which can be set at the system level and overridden at the job level.  Here's the help text from Jenkins:

If set, a newly scheduled build waits for this many seconds before actually being built. This is useful for:
Collapsing multiple CVS change notification e-mails into one (some CVS changelog e-mail generation scripts generate multiple e-mails in quick succession when a commit spans across directories).

If your coding style is such that you commit one logical change in a few cvs/svn operations, then setting a longer quiet period would prevent Jenkins from building it prematurely and reporting a failure.

Throttling builds. If your Jenkins installation is too busy with too many builds, setting a longer quiet period can reduce the number of builds.

If not explicitly set at project-level, the system-wide default value is used.

And here is a [more detailed discussion](http://jenkins-ci.org/content/quiet-period-feature).

Comment: Just found this setting hiding in the Advanced properties, exactly what I need.  Thanks!!